# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Return this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error" when trying to add item in list. In the other words it's return error in  addtoNote.Add(Name); and am sure that Name is not null.

```
protected void features(string Name, string shortName)
{ List<string> addtoNote =  ViewState["Note"] as List<string> ;
    if (Name.Length > 0)
    {
        addtoNote.Add(Name);
    } else
    {for (int x = 0; x < addtoNote.Count; x++)
        {if (addtoNote[x].StartsWith(shortName))
            {
                addtoNote.RemoveAt(x);}
        } }
    ViewState["Note"] = addtoNote;
    TxtNote.Text = string.Join(TxtNote.Text , ",", addtoNote);
}
protected void ChkPersonalAccedent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{if (ChkPersonalAccedent.Checked == true)
    { features("حوادث شخصية", "حوادث شخصية");}
    else
     { features("", "حوادث شخصية"); }}
```

Comment: Please, for your own sanity, press Ctrl+K, D in Visual Studio to format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ViewState["Note"]` is **not** a `List<string>`, this expression

```
ViewState["Note"] as List<string>;
```

will return `null`. So `addtoNote` is null and that is why the runtime exception is thrown.

Comment: How to fix it   , no ViewState["Note"]  and List<string> is same

Comment: You can exclude null list from your `if` statement `if( Name.Length > 0 && addtoNote != null)` @rere